# Register additional component implementations for a service at runtime in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

Using Castle Windsor I can register multiple implementations of a type e.g.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyInterceptor>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyInterceptor>();

container.Register(Component.For<IMyInterceptor>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyInterceptor2>();
```

This all works as you'd expect and I can resolve multiple implementations using ResolveAll()

If I try to register an instance of another implementation at runtime though - e.g.

```
var interceptor = new MyInterceptor3();
Container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyInterceptor>()
        .Instance(interceptor));
```

I get an exception:

There is a component already registered for the given key MyInterceptor3

Is this the expected behaviour? What I'm trying to acheive is to use e.g. Container.ResolveAll() to get a list of default implementations of IMyInterceptor plus optional additional implementations (i.e. on a request by request basis, when debug modes are enabled).

Comment: My collegue pointed me to this link http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-one-by-one&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 
Specifically:
Registering instance ignores lifestyle
When you register an existing instance, even if you specify a lifestyle it will be ignored. Also registering instance, will set the implementation type for you, so if you  try to do it manually, an exception will be thrown.
So it looks like instances are always Singleton in nature (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sort you out.

```
var interceptor = new MyInterceptor3();
Container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyInterceptor>()
        .Instance(interceptor).Named("something unique));
```

Names must be unique.

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue I am having is that I am trying to register the components as PerWebRequest. In the 'Instance()' case this is being ignored (as per comment  above) so that on the second request I get the exception (i.e. when trying to overwrite the existing component (?)).

Comment: Interestingly, digging in the OpenRasta codebase, there seems to be a workaround this this, using a custom component https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-castle-windsor/blob/master/src/OpenRasta.DI.Windsor/WindsorDependencyResolver.cs (see AddDependencyInstanceCore()). I have used this functionality before through OR which may explain why I was confused as to the expected Castle behaviour